# Retrieve all available masking policies for an account in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-data-masking

How to get all the masking policies created in a particular account in snowflake? Is there any view to see it?

show masking policies only retrieves data related to the policies and not where it is applied?

How can I get all policies and in which columns in which tables it is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the information schema table-function POLICY_REFERENCES, see here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/policy_references.html

Here is also an example from the docs:

```
use database my_db;
use schema information_schema;
select *
  from table(information_schema.policy_references(policy_name => 'ssn_mask'));
```

Important: You have to execute the `USE DATABASE ...` and `USE SCHEMA INFORMATION_SCHEMA` commands or use a full qualified identifier.

If this is not enough, you can query all policies with all tables and all columns when you combine the query above with your `SHOW MASKING POLICIES;` and the RESULT_SCAN()-function.
RESULT_SCAN() allows you to query the results of `SHOW MASKING POLICIES;` (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html)

Consequence: You get all names of policies and for each of them you can call POLICY_REFERENCES().